# Access i-th element in a certain field of all records of a non-scalar structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have a structure named mystruct with two fields: `field1`, `field2`. A typical example:

```
mystruct(1).field1 = 'a'
mystruct(1).field2 = [100 200 300] % an array of elements

mystruct(2).field1 = 'b'
mystruct(2).field2 = [700 800 900] % an array of elements
```

How can I access to first element of `field2` in each record (e.g. 100 and 700 in the above example) without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant solution could be using [**`arrayfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
ii = 1;
out = arrayfun(@(x) x.field2(ii), mystruct)
```

which is basically another notation for this simple loop:

```
ii = 1;
for jj = 1:numel(mystruct)
    out(jj) = mystruct(jj).field2(ii);
end
```

In case you have *a lot* of fields and **all arrays have the same length**, then you could consider the following solution, which is more vectorized and maybe a little faster.

```
ii = 1;
X = vertcat( mystruct(:).field2 )
out = X(:,ii)
```

---

```
out =

   100
   700
```